# How to replace several lines but not the last

Tags: sed, replace, insert

I need to remove lines from word "WORDA" to the last "}" before WORDB.
But there are other "}" before. So SED missed the selection.

```
...
WORDA
{
blah
  {
  blahblah
  ...
  blahblahblah
  }
}
WORDB 0
...
```

So I'm trying to replace from "WORDA" to "WORDB" with "WORDB" but I lose the "0" at the end... The result is not inserted... All the last line is replaced.
(Of course, this "0" value can be any other number.)

```
sed.exe -i /WORDA/,/WORDB/c\WORDB\ file
```

result

```
...
WORDB
...
```

but I need:

```
...
WORDB 0
...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Crude but effective:

```
sed '/WORDA/,/WORDB/{/WORDB/!d;}' filename
```